# slice strings of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

i am getting below array.

```
Array [
  "מאי 2017",
  "יוני 2017",
  "ינואר 2018",
  "פברואר 2018",
  "מרץ 2018",
  "מאי 2018",
  "יוני 2018",
  "נובמבר 2019",
  "אוגוסט 2020",
  "נובמבר 2020",
  "דצמבר 2020",
  "ינואר 2021",
]
```

and i have an english month array.

```
const englishMonthArray = [
    "",
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ]
```

how can i match only months of  above array with English months?Thanks

Comment: I may not understand the question but I don't see any English months here.

Comment: now you can see there is an english month array.please give the solution.

Comment: Are you asking how to produce a new array that replaces the Hebrew month with the English equivalent? So "מאי 2017" would become "2017 May", for example?

Comment: yes..thats what i want @Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a dictionary object that maps the Hebrew month (key) to the English equivalent (value).
2. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array. [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string on the space, get the English month from the dictionary, and then return a new string.

```js
const arr=["מאי 2017","יוני 2017","ינואר 2018","פברואר 2018","מרץ 2018","מאי 2018","יוני 2018","נובמבר 2019","אוגוסט 2020","נובמבר 2020","דצמבר 2020","ינואר 2021"];

const dict = {
  ינואר: 'January',
  פברואר: 'February',
  מרץ: 'March',
  אַפּרִיל: 'April', 
  מאי: 'May',
  יוני: 'June',
  יולי: 'July',
  אוגוסט: 'August',
  יולי: 'September',
  יולי: 'October',
  נובמבר: 'November',
  דצמבר: 'December'
};

const out = arr.map(el => {

  // This was interesting. For an English string
  // this would be destructured like [year, month].
  // I'm assuming that because there's Hebrew in the string
  // JS/the browser reads it differently (right to left).
  const [ month, year ] = el.split(' ');
  const enMonth = dict[month];
  return `${year} ${enMonth}`;
});

console.log(out);
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)